# Custom PHP MVC and issue with AJAX, JSON Unexpected token D in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I have issue with my built from scratch PHP MVC and implementation of AJAX in jQuery where form is sending a text data, the received data in the JS file which is included in the Dashboard class construct ;

**Model (`dashboard_model.php`)**

```
<?php
class Dashboard_Model extends Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        # code...
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function xhrInsert(){
        $text = $_POST['text'];

        $sth = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO data (text) VALUES (:text)');
        $sth->execute(array(':text' => $text));

        $data = array('text' => $text, 'id' => $this->db->lastInsertId());
        print json_encode($data);
    }

    function xhrGetListings(){
        $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM data');
        $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $sth->execute();
        $data = $sth->fetchAll();
        print json_encode($data);

    }

    function xhrDeleteListing(){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sth = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM data WHERE id ="'.$id.'"');
        $sth->execute();
    }

}
?>
```

**Controller (`dashboard.php`)**

It calls renderer for default js file which handles the ajax callback.

```
<?php
class Dashboard extends Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        # code...
        parent::__construct();

        Session::init();
        $logged = Session::get('loggedin');
        if($logged == false){
            Session::destroy();
            header('location: ../login');
            exit;
        } 

        $this->view->js = array('dashboard/js/default.js');
    }

    function index() {
        $this->view->render('dashboard/index');
    }

    function logout() {
            Session::destroy();
            header('location: ../login');
            exit;
    }

    function xhrInsert()    // xml  http request  ajax
    {
        $this->model->xhrInsert();
    }

    function xhrGetListings(){
        $this->model->xhrGetListings();
    }

    function xhrDeleteListing(){
        $this->model->xhrDeleteListing();
    }
}
?>
```

```js
$(function() {

 $.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function(o){
  //console.log(o);
  for (var  i =0; i<o.length; i++)
  {
   $('#listInserts').append('s<div>'+o[i].text+'<a class="del" rel="'+ o[i].id +'" href="#">X</a></div>');
  }

  $('.del').click(function(){
   delItem = $(this);
   var id = $(this).attr('rel');
   
   $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'id': id}, function(o){
    delItem.parent().remove();
   }, 'json');

   return false;
  });

 },'json'); 

 $('#randomInsert').on('submit', function(){
  var url = $(this).attr('action');
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  
  console.log('data received : '+data);
  

  $.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'post',
   data: data,
   beforeSend : function(xhr){
    console.log('before'+xhr);
   },
   success : function(data, status, xhr){
    console.log(data);
    $('#listInserts').append('<div>'+data.text+'<a class="del" rel="'+ data.id +'" href="#">X</a></div>');
   },
   error: function(xhr, status, error){
    console.log('erreur ajax');
    console.log('jqXHR =' + xhr + '|status='+status + '|error='+error);
   },
   complete: function(xhr, status){
    console.log('complete xhr = ' + xhr + '|status=' + status);
   },
   statusCode : {
    404 : function() {
     console.log('STATUSCODE : 404 Page not found');
    }
   }
  });
  return false;
 });



});
```

```html
<br/>

<form id="randomInsert" action="<?PHP echo URL; ?>dashboard/xhrInsert" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="text" />
 <input type="submit"  />

</form>

<div id="listInserts">

</div>
```

The results seen on Chrome developer are:

```
data received : text=qsdfq
default.js:35 before[object Object]
default.js:38 Dashboard Object
(
    [view] => View Object
        (
            [js] => Array
                (
                    [0] => dashboard/js/default.js
                )

        )

    [model] => Dashboard_Model Object
        (
            [db] => Database Object
                (
                )

        )

)
{"text":"qsdfq","id":"102"}
default.js:46 complete xhr = [object Object]|status=success
```

Of course this is not desired result since it shows Undefined and it does not pull out JSON data even if I put JSON type data in jQuery

The XHR response on Chrome developer tool is :

```
Dashboard Object ( [view] => View Object ( [js] => Array ( [0] => dashboard/js/default.js ) ) [model] => Dashboard_Model Object ( [db] => Database Object ( ) ) ) {"text":"qsdfq","id":"102"}
```

**The main issue appears to be with those added things**:

```
Dashboard Object ( [view] => View Object ( [js] => Array ( [0] => dashboard/js/default.js ) ) [model] => Dashboard_Model Object ( [db] => Database Object ( ) ) )
```

On top of the returned ajax result to be process in the jquery `$.get` or `$.post` with data type json!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which MVC you are using. You identified problem in questions.

Response from  your code is:-

```
Dashboard Object ( [view] => View Object ( [js] => Array ( [0] => dashboard/js/default.js ) ) [model] => Dashboard_Model Object ( [db] => Database Object ( ) ) ) {"text":"qsdfq","id":"102"}
```

Problem Caused due to return of:-

```
Dashboard Object ( [view] => View Object ( [js] => Array ( [0] => dashboard/js/default.js ) ) [model] => Dashboard_Model Object ( [db] => Database Object ( ) ) )
```

Your code works fine if you receive:-

```
{"text":"qsdfq","id":"102"}
```

Here is my suggestion if this works for you. First check your Model and Write change your function to:-

```
function xhrInsert(){
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    $sth = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO data (text) VALUES (:text)');
    $sth->execute(array(':text' => $text));

    $data = array('text' => $text, 'id' => $this->db->lastInsertId());
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Now move to controller and change your function:-

```
function xhrInsert()    // xml  http request  ajax
{
    $data = $this->model->xhrInsert();
    echo $data;
    die;
}
```

If above didn't work try this

```
function xhrInsert()    // xml  http request  ajax
{
    $data = $this->model->xhrInsert();
    return $data;
}
```

If both option didn't work finally make a view for it and echo data inside view.

```
function xhrInsert()    // xml  http request  ajax
{
    $data = $this->model->xhrInsert();
    //Something like below
    $this->view->render('dashboard/insert', ['data' => $data]);
}
```